# Determine number of columns in printed page

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2007, I have a worksheet that only contains data in a only few cells (well within one page wide/tall). For illustration, say the worksheet only contains data in cell `A1`. How can I use VBA to determine the number of columns that fit in a single printed page? Said another way, how can I determine the column furthest to the right in which I could add data and NOT cause an additional sheet to print. A couple of additional comments:

- I am not setting a print area. If I were, then I'd just use the same
  range...but I'm not.
- I can't use `UsedRange`, because the used range is much smaller than
  what actually fits in the width/height of a printed page.
- I can't use `ActiveWindow.VisibleRange` because it isn't limited to a
  single page width/height.

I've searched and searched, but cannot find a solution to accomplish this seemingly simple task. I mostly found scenarios that involved `UsedRange`, `VisibleRange`, and the print area, but those don't help me.

**EDIT**

Here's the final version of the function I'm using, which is a slight tweak of the selected answer.

```
Public Function GetLastColumnBeforeVPageBreak( _
        ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal aVPageBreakNum As Long) As Long
    Dim isMod As Boolean

    isMod = False

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    GetLastColumnBeforeVPageBreak = ws.VPageBreaks(aVPageBreakNum).Location.Column - 1

    ' If necessary, delete the last column with dummy data and reset UsedRange.
    If isMod Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete
        r = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End If

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        ' Subscript out of range.
        ' Ensure there is more than one page by putting something in last cell.
        isMod = True
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns.Count).Value = 1
        Err.Clear
        Resume
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: hi @neizan, have you found any better way to do this? I'm having a very similar problem at the moment. Please see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824898/how-to-adjust-chart-size-to-fit-page-size-using-excel-vba#comment36662291_23824898                I need to find the printed area minus all the margins. I can successfully get the last column using your method and work out the boundary myself. It just doesn't look like a decent solution. If you managed to find a better way to do this, please can you let me know as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was sure there was a worksheet property around page breaks so I hit F2 in the IDE to open the object browser and searched on `pagebreak`. A little bit of F1'ing showed there is a `Worksheets(1).VPageBreaks(1).Location` property that returns a range object. The left side of the range aligns with the 1st vertical page break so:

```
LastColOnP1 = Worksheets(1).VPageBreaks(1).Location.Column - 1
```

will give you a variable containing the number of the last column that will print on page 1 of your 1st sheet.

Or within a procedure:

```
Sub FindFirstVPageBreak()
Dim LastColOnP1 As Long

With ActiveSheet
    'Ensure there is more than one page by puting something in last column
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count) = 1
    LastColOnP1 = .VPageBreaks(1).Location.Column - 1
    'Delete the last column to allow UsedRange to be reset
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
'Save to workbook to commit the reset UsedRange
If Not ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save 'assumes workbook has been saved previously.
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but I get a `subscript out of range` error. So I checked and `ws.VPageBreaks.Count = 0`. I haven't set any page breaks, so I guess that's the issue. Any way around that?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me, and I have been trying to go another (longer) route. If there is some way to use this, I would much rather do it. I used your exact code and got the aforementioned error. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my edit above. Inital test was on a sheet that spanned 30 columns so it already had `VPageBreaks`. Further test on a blank sheet did produce a `Subscript out of range` error because there aren't any. In fact, on a blank sheet you can't even do a Print Preview because there is nothing to print. Note if you aren't referencing the `UsedRange` elsewhere in your code, you can dispense with the `Save` step.

Comment: This worked great. The only thing is it's a little slow. I tried some modifications to speed things up with limited success. I've posted the final function in an edit to my question. This is what I'll use. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Columns(x).ColumnWidth to calculate (iif column contains data).  See http://EzineArticles.com/7305778 for a much more detailed solution.

Comment: Along the lines of:
    Dim i As Integer 
     For i = 1 To 20 
        Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 2 
        c = c + Columns(i).ColumnWidth 
    Next i

Comment: I checked out the link. I think I might be able to get something to work using something like that. If I can get Mark Fitzgerald's way to work for me, then I'll use it as it's much more direct. If not, I'll try the approach you've suggested.

Comment: A line of code (in the Ezine article) is `pgWid = Application.InchesToPoints(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize)`. However, `.PaperSize` gives the integer value of the PaperSize Enumeration, not a width dimension in inches. I implemented a helper function to get around that, but I'm getting errors that some page sizes are not recognized. After doing a few quick tests, it seems the PageSize Enumeration values in the Excel help file are not accurate. Furthermore, for the paper sizes that are recognized correctly, I'm getting incorrect final column values. See new code above.