# How to adjust chart size to fit page size using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to adjust the size of a chart in Excel to exactly fit the printable area, e.g. the chart should cover the whole A4 page ***except the margin area***, i.e. it should cover the area of `(A4 height - top and bottom margins) x (A4 width - left and right margins)`. I have tried the following code but it turned out that the height of the chart is very close to but still not quite the same as (A4 height - top and bottom margins), whereas the width is about 1 cell wider than (A4 width - left and right margins).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim objChartShape As Chart

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh.ChartObjects.Count <> 0 Then
        sh.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Set objChartShape = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    Dim w, h As Long
    w = Application.CentimetersToPoints(21#) ' A4 width in cm
    h = Application.CentimetersToPoints(29.7) ' A4 height in cm
    w = w - sh.PageSetup.LeftMargin - sh.PageSetup.RightMargin
    h = h - sh.PageSetup.TopMargin - sh.PageSetup.BottomMargin
    With objChartShape
        .Parent.Left = 0
        .Parent.Top = 0
        .Parent.Width = w
        .Parent.Height = h
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code create an empty chart when the sheet is activated. You will see that the chart is not high enough to reach the top of the footer area and it is too wide to fit within a single page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You know that you can move a chart to its own sheet where you can set the size to A4 and the margin under view?

Comment: Cheers, @Siphor. It doesn't really matter to me whether the chart is in its own sheet or not. The problem is how to set its size to A4 minus all the margins. My code above attempted to do so but didn't work.

Comment: Old question, but here goes. You're working with a chart object embedded in a worksheet. Perhaps using a chart sheet directly would be better, since it automatically is resized to fit within the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to also account for the header and footer margin?:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim objChartShape As Chart

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh.ChartObjects.Count <> 0 Then
        sh.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Set objChartShape = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    Dim w, h As Long
    w = Application.CentimetersToPoints(21#) ' A4 width in cm
    h = Application.CentimetersToPoints(29.7) ' A4 height in cm
    w = w - sh.PageSetup.LeftMargin - sh.PageSetup.RightMargin
    h = h - sh.PageSetup.TopMargin - sh.PageSetup.BottomMargin - sh.PageSetup.HeaderMargin - sh.PageSetup.FooterMargin
    With objChartShape
        .Parent.Left = 0
        .Parent.Top = 0
        .Parent.Width = w
        .Parent.Height = h
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers, @Dave.Gugg, I'm afraid this doesn't work. I've tried exactly the same code at first and I realized that   the header margin is within the top margin and the footer margin is within the bottom margin. Further more, this doesn't change the width of the chart which doesn't fit the page size, either.